# Rollbacking syspreps

Tags: administration

Imagine, I'm stupid coder. I have completely configured PC, in my company's domain.
I tried to solve one my stupid problem and found manual. First step was
"run sysprep.exe /audit /reboot"

I didn't knew what is purpose of sysprep and simply made this step.

After that my OS was rebooted and after boot always showing screen "Systep Preparation Tool 3.14".

After that I said "Oops" and now I'm searching for rollback algorythm. I want go to the past to the place, where I never knew or used this stupid app: syspreps.exe.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but as far as I know there is no rollback (unless you have backed up your system before you did and use a system restore).

The purpose of `sysprep` is to prepare customized Windows installations for OEMs for their Desktop PCs or Notebooks. It will remove user profiles and user related stuff from your Windows and reset them to a state from which a set up can be invoked.

To avoid accidents like this I suggest that you use tools such as VMWare, VMWare Player, Virtual Box or Virtual PC to set up a virtual machine. Take snapshots which is done in a few minutes and you can rollback to the previous state very easily.

More information about sysprep you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15118641/1016343), please follow the links in my answer there.